# kafka daemon consumer Java

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

would like to create a daemon service(java) in linux machine which is a kafka consumer ...

Please suggest a sample!!.

Came across this 
[Kafka Consumer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468024/kafka-consumer-in-java)

not sure if i can use daemon service..

and have one more query...
from the documentation of kafka came to know that consumer follows pull model...as
per my understanding consumer continuosly polls the kafka server for messages...

- Is there any sleep time for consumer as it continuosuly polls.
- how the consumer knows from which offset it has to read the message in the kafka server.
- If consumer goes down while reading how will it persist the offset from where it has to read the message in the server...

Im newbie to kafka!!